# Getting Spells IDs from WoW

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there a way to get all the current spell IDs using Blizzard's WoW API?

I would like to know the exact IDs because there are spells that might have IDs as low as 3 and up to 8056, while the limit of requests to do is around 3k for anonymous calls and 9k for registered applications (and this shuts down the idea of just trying to get the IDs in an 'for' expression).

Having the exact IDs of the spells, I can safely use Blizzard's API without worrying much about those limits.

Comment: Wowhead has the spell IDs, but that's not really what you're asking. I'm unsure of how to do this via Blizzard's UI, and it sounds like you need them in bulk so just scraping Wowhead probably isn't a great solution either.

Comment: Yup. It looks like Wowhead has its own IDs for referring their own content, so they would be useless with Blizzard's API. If there is a way to get them in bulk, that would be great.

Comment: Won't this be off-topic? I see programming related stuff

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that, since it is related to Blizzard, this would be a suitable place. I will repost it into other stackexchange then. :)

Comment: Funny, when I registered an app just now, it gave me 100 calls per second and 36000 per day.

Comment: ElvUI and other UI addons have this function.

Comment: It's easy to do it yourself.. use the spell api `GET SPELL /WOW/SPELL/:SPELLID` and request spell 1 - N in a loop. Save them in a xml or something with name id class combination e.g. so you can use it later for addons or sth. The call limit should be per day/week if i remember right so you've to do it only once and back up the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you dont like a for loop answer I'll give you one.
The Blizzard api has the function [GET SPELL /WOW/SPELL/:SPELLID](https://dev.battle.net/io-docs) to recieve spell information. Run that function in a loop, request all available spells and back them up in a xml file.

I give you that answer because I found the following in the [Blizzard forum](http://us.battle.net/en/forum/topic/15255185550).

> Hey community devs!
>
> Since we launched the new API endpoints a number of you have run into
>   issues related to the API request quota (10 calls per second). I’m
>   pleased to announce that we’re changing out API requests are throttled
>   in order to make it easier to develop against our APIs.
>
> UPDATE: Throttle raised from 10 cps to 100 cps NEW: **36,000 calls per
>   hour** quota
>
> These new limits maintain the same total call throughput, but allows
>   devs to burst requests as necessary.

This post is dated 11/13/2014.

That should be more than enough for your plan.